# How to get line breaks in equation when knitting to pdf?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I'm trying to knit a document that has an equation in it and I would like the equation to respect linebreaks.   This works fine when I knit to HTML but does not when I knit to pdf.

```
$$ 
x_1 - ? +\\
x_2 - ? +\\
x_3 - ? +\\
$$
```

I've also tried `\newline` and even `\hfill \break`.  I also tried the different latex engines listed on the RMarkdown cheat sheet at RStudio.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `Latex` code:

```
\begin{aligned}
x_1 - ? + \\
x_2 - ? + \\
x_3 - ? + 
\end{aligned}
```

If you do not want a numbered equation, use

```
\begin{aligned}
x_1 - ? + \nonumber \\
x_2 - ? + \nonumber \\
x_3 - ? + \nonumber
\end{aligned}
```

This works in HTML and PDF.

Comment: If you get `Package amsmath Error: \begin{aligned} allowed only in math mode.` surround the above with `\begin{math}...\end{math}`

Comment: What if I *do* want an equation number?